# Why are jpeg.Decode(bytes.NewReader(imageBytes)) and jpeg.Encode(buf, img, nil) from Bild eating up a lot of CPU?

Tags: image, go

I am trying to build an application which manipulates images on the run using [Bild](https://github.com/anthonynsimon/bild). But the above-mentioned methods are eating up a lot CPU(90%) for images. What is the reason for these methods to use high CPU?
Are there any other methods or packages which uses less CPU?

```
func imageDecode(imageBytes []byte) (image.Image, error) {
    contentType := http.DetectContentType(imageBytes)
    var err error
    var img image.Image
    if contentType == constants.PngContentType {
        img, err = png.Decode(bytes.NewReader(imageBytes))
    } else if contentType == constants.JpegContentType {
        img, err = jpeg.Decode(bytes.NewReader(imageBytes))
    } else if contentType == constants.GifContentType {
        img, err = gif.Decode(bytes.NewReader(imageBytes))
    } else {
        img, err = nil, fmt.Errorf("decode error invalid content-type for filename: ")
    }
    if err != nil {
        return img, err
    }
    return img, nil
}

func imageEncode(imageBytes []byte, img image.Image) ([]byte, error) {
    contentType := http.DetectContentType(imageBytes)
    if contentType == constants.PngContentType && isOpaque(img) {
        contentType = constants.JpegContentType
    }
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    var err error
    var transformedImageBytes []byte
    if contentType == constants.PngContentType {
        pngEnc := png.Encoder{CompressionLevel: png.BestCompression}
        err = pngEnc.Encode(buf, img)
    } else if contentType == constants.JpegContentType {
        err = jpeg.Encode(buf, img, nil)
    } else if contentType == constants.GifContentType {
        err = gif.Encode(buf, img, nil)
    } else {
        err = fmt.Errorf("encode error invalid content-type")
    }
    if err != nil {
        return transformedImageBytes, err
    }
    transformedImageBytes = buf.Bytes()
    return transformedImageBytes, err
}
```

Comment: We don't know how you use them. Code samples would be helpful. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: The sample code is written above! And I am using  8 CPU's and testing at a rate of 50 rps!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually detect the image type and use different decoding calls, the `image` package does that for you already, when using [`image.Decode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Decode). Just make sure you have the image decoders registered prior, which you can achieve by using blank imports, e.g.:

```
import (
    _ "image/gif"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    _ "image/png"
)

func imageDecode(imageBytes []byte) (image.Image, error) {
    img, _, err := image.Decode(bytes.NewReader(imageBytes))
}
```

Although I'm not sure performance will improve significantly by this.

What you should do is use "smart" conversion. By this I mean in certain cases you can omit decoding and re-encoding the image, you can just send the input to the output as-is (e.g. using [`io.Copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy)):

- If input is a GIF image.
- If input is a JPEG image.

You only have to truly decode the image if it is of PNG format. Note that detecting if a PNG image is opaque is slow as it has to examine all the pixels (unless a transparent pixel is found earlier).

Comment: I what scenarios do we use io.copy()? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Sainath I assume this image conversion is called from HTTP handlers. If so, you can use `io.Copy()` to copy the input image (wrapped in `bytes.Buffer`)  to the `http.ResponseWriter`. If not, just return the input `imageBytes` as the output byte slice if no conversion is needed.